# Getting video metadata in ruby script using ffmpeg, ffprobe or rvideo

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg

I want to get metadata of videos referenced by a URL using Ruby. At this point, I found many related posts, but could not find out how to solve my problem.

I tried to use RVideo, but when I do:

> file = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => 'http://www.agreatsite.com/avideo.mp4')

It throws

> 'ArgumentError: File not found (http://www.agreatsite.com/avideo.mp4)...

So I can't get the information using RVideo (but it works well when I have the file hosted on my local computer).

I then tried to use ffprobe, but I don't know how to read the output.
So far, I have the following method, which "shows" the information I want when I run it in the console, but it actually returns "true" and I can't find out how to capture the output I need...

> ```
>   def media_info
>     source = self
>     command = <<-end_command
>       ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams  #{source}
>     end_command
>     command.gsub!(/\s+/, " ")
>     system(command)
>   end
> ```

Would love some help, to make this work with either ffprobe or RVideo!

UPDATE:
I found a way to get what I needed. Not sure this is the best way to do it:

> def get_media_duration
>
> ```
> source = self.media[0][:url]    
>
> command = <<-end_command
>   ffprobe -v quiet  -show_streams  #{source}
> end_command
> command.gsub!(/\s+/, " ")
>
> duration = ""
> IO.popen(command) { |io| while (line = io.gets) do
>                         puts "++ "+line.inspect
>                         duration = line.split("duration=")[1].gsub("\n", "") if line.split("duration=").length > 1
>                       end
>                   }
> duration
> ```
>
> end

I guess I could make it work that way, but doesn't seem very elegant to me. Better suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I can help, but I found this in the ffmpeg documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#concat .  Of course, the ruby lib you are using essentially runs `ffmpeg -i` which does not accept a URL.  Perhaps you can hack around it

Comment: You are trying to open a file from a remote location, I'm not sure if `RVideo::Inspector` handles that the way you assume it does.

Answer (score 2):

Check streamio-ffmpeg, If you are still looking for a solution. Also ffprobe supports json format now:  `ffprobe -print_format json -show_streams #{input_file}`