# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory in finding duration of video from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

Using gem paperclip-ffmpeg in rails for videos.It works fine but when I find the duration of video in seconds it gives me an error

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - the file 'http://getpayad-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/ads/videos/000/000/014/original/Ufone_Tarzan_commercial_%28Ufone_Network_Quality%29_most_Funny_Ad.mp4?1451555000' does not exist
from /home/des0071/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/streamio-ffmpeg-1.0.0/lib/ffmpeg/movie.rb:11:in `initialize
```

My code is

```
movie  = FFMPEG::Movie.new("#{self.video.url}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the FFMPEG::Movie.new definition is found here: [streamio-ffmpeg/movie.rb](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/ffmpeg/movie.rb#L11)

> ```
> raise Errno::ENOENT, "the file '#{path}' does not exist" unless File.exists?(path)
> ```

```
#ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005)
File.exists?("http://getpayad-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/ads/videos/000/000/014/original/Ufone_Tarzan_commercial_%28Ufone_Network_Quality%29_most_Funny_Ad.mp4?1451555000")
=> false
```

The problem is with ruby's File Class.  So I tried this:

```
   File.exists?("http://www.google.com")
   => false
```

OK, so either google isn't online or File can't take URI as a parameter.

> A File is an abstraction of any file object accessible by the program and is closely associated with class IO File includes the methods of module FileTest as class methods, allowing you to write (for example) File.exist?("foo").
>   [Class: File Ruby 2.2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html)

So, File Class is really a child of IO, what does IO say?

> Many of the examples in this section use the File class, the only standard subclass of IO. The two classes are closely associated. Like the File class, the Socket library subclasses from IO (such as TCPSocket or UDPSocket).
>   [Class:IO Ruby 2.2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html)

It looks like the reason for the error is due to inheritance, or because the gem is not designed to stream the file over http.

Comment: :( Any solution of it

Comment: The problem is the Gem has limitations that restrict it to local file processing, because metadata is not its primary function.  Here's a question that demonstrates how to utilize an external binary, ffprobe, that can receive a uri argument.  [getting video metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919427/getting-video-metadata-in-ruby-script-using-ffmpeg-ffprobe-or-rvideo)

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer suggestions, ffmpeg doesn't appear to be able to fetch the file over HTTP -- it's expecting a local file.

Depending upon how your files are encoded, they may have metadata at the beginning or end of the file which contains this information.

Subsequently a potential approach is to grab the first or last ~100KB of the file and check for the MOOV atom/metadata there.